# Accesing delegate static method in Objective-c issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, delegates, protocols

I have a weird problem in objective-c. Here is the code:

STViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface STViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
+(void)myStaticMethod;
@end
```

STViewController.m

```
#import "STViewController.h"

@implementation STViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [STViewController myStaticMethod];
}

+ (void)myStaticMethod {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Foo bar"
                                                    message:@"baz bat"
    //what does self even mean in this context? The class object STViewController?
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

#pragma mark UIAlertViewDelegate

// TRICKY PART if it's static it works, if it's not, it doesn't.
// even though the protocol declares instance methods (with a minus).
+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"It works!");
}

@end
```

Why does this happen? Is this correct? I receive no errors or warnings. Does the -/+ in the protocol methods declaration do something?

Comment: There is no self in a class method's scope. You could reference a singleton though.

Comment: @NickWeaver you can use `self` in class method, it will point to `Class` object as `[MyClass class]`

Comment: There are no "static methods" in Objective-C. There are "class methods" and "instance methods". "Static method" implies that the method lookup is done statically at compile time, which never happens in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to know that a `Class` (normally get from `[MyClass class]`) object is also an valid ObjC object. This means that you can send message to class object as well.

For example

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (NSString *)name;
@end

@implementation MyClass
+ (NSString *)name {
    return NSStringFromClass(self); // note in class method, self == [MyClass class]
}
@end

// ------- in some method

id cls = [MyClass class]; // the correct type should be Class, but since Class is an object, id will also work
NSLog(@"%@", [cls name]); // call like instance method - MyClass
NSLog(@"%@", [MyClass name]); // call like class method - MyClass
```

so you can use your class object like other object and call the class method like instance method.

and class methods are actually instance methods!! the difference is that class methods are instance methods of **metaclass**, which is the class of `Class`. for more about metaclass: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html

---

also, your class interface is incorrect, because it is not possible (at least at compiler time) to add a protocol to a metaclass. so if you do `[self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIAlertViewDelegate)]` will return NO. but you implemented `+ alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` which will add this method as the instance method of the metaclass, so the delegate code works and `[self responseToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]` will return YES.

Comment: Please don't say "`Class` object". It makes it sound like `Class` is a class.

Comment: just "class object" (lowercase) would be fine I think

Answer (score 2):

In class methods `self` refers to the class object. The class object is a normal objc object (derived from `NSObject`) that will receive messages sent to the class (class methods, those with the "+").

In your case, you used the class object as a delegate of a `UIAlertView` (which works because the API of UIAlertView does not explicitly require an object of static type `id<UIAlertViewDelegate>`). Now the alert view would just send it's delegate messages to the class object which again is fine, as you implemented them as class methods.

Comment: In the header of the UIAlertView I see there is  this line: @property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;. The protocol is commented out. Why is this not id<UIAlertViewDelegate> ? If it would not be commented, would my code still work?

Comment: "derived from NSObject" well technically, derived from the root class of the class, which in this case, is NSObject

Comment: @CristianIlea: 1. I have no idea why they commented it out. 2. If it were not commented out, the compiler might give you a warning. 3. Whether it works at runtime depends on how `UIAlertView` is implemented. If it checks whether the delegate object actually conforms to the protocol (using `conformsToProtocol:`), it won't work. But no Cocoa API ever does that. If it just checks that the delegate responds to the selector (using `respondsToSelector:`), then it will work.

Answer (score -3):

You are setting `self` as alert delegate which is dynamic - but method calling that is static so that is wrong in the first place, because when you will call `+ (void)myStaticMethod` some time in a future `self` might be uninitialized and be `nil`. That why other errors may follow as well as undefined behavior