# Objective C - How to change image from another class (another UIViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I'm using `NSObject` class to handle a few server methods.

One of the methods is to download images from DB (parse.com).

The problem is that the `UIViewController` who present the image is loaded faster than the download process (the image always `nil`), and only 2 sec after that the image is in the device.

How can I update the `UIImageView` image (userProfile class) from the `NSObject` class (the one with the download method)?

- I'm not using navigation bar - but the `UIViewController` with the image is in `UITabBar`

I know how to detect the end of the downloading process but I don't know how to reach to the UIImageView property from the other class.

Comment: You could use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation). This will allow you to update your image in asynch manner.

Comment: Are you getting any event when you finish downloading your image ?

Comment: Yes, I know how to detect the end of the downloading process but I don't know how to reach to the UIImageView property from the other class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `delegate` for your requirement. Check [implement delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626946/1106035) or [ios_delegates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm) how it can be done.

Some understanding is given below :

Say u have delegate method in NSObject class to handle a few server methods

```
@protocol YouNSObjectClassDelegate <NSObject>
@required
  -(void)imageDownloaded:(UIImage*)image;
@end
```

Add

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<YouNSObjectClassDelegate> delegate;
```

While allocating object any any viewcontroller , don't forgot to intialize delegate

```
yourNSObjectClassObject.delegate = self;
```

When image is downloaded in NSObject class

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageDownloaded:)]) {
    [delegate imageDownloaded:image];
}
```

In  UIViewController  where u want to have image add these method

```
-(void)imageDownloaded:(UIImage*)image
{
   //Set Image here
}
```

Comment: I think this can be the answer but I've never worked with delegates like this before. can your please be more specific how to do it and where I need to write everything?

Comment: @Asi Givati Check now

Comment: Thanks. It still not work for me so well, but I'm sure this is the right answer. I think I'm doing something wrong. in the 'NSObject' class .m the delegate is not recognized even if I use '@synthesize'. I get error like this 'Instance variable 'delegate' accessed in class method'.

Comment: Ohh.. now I know why - my download method is static

Comment: Is it possible to use delegate with static method?

Comment: Check these links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085317/accesing-delegate-static-method-in-objective-c-issue and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883521/can-i-use-a-class-method-as-a-delegate-callback

Comment: Could be done a heck of a lot easier with a completion block.

Comment: why don't you edit answer and show how can it can be done with completion block.

Answer (score 1):

while you calling `NSObject Class` just pass your `UIImageView` with other parameters and when your image got downloaded just set new image to the `UIImageView`. I guess you are using threading concept so update your `UIImageView` only on `Main Thread`. You can use either

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Set your Image to UIImageView
    });
```

OR use

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImage:) withObject:objects waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Or better you can write your own `block` or `delegate` method and pass downloaded image when image got downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In the tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, rather than setting the image directly, use GCD async and a completion block.

In your download class header declare a new method with completion block:

```
- (void)downloadImagesWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

And the implementation:

```
- (void)downloadImagesWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NO), ^(void){
        // Run your downloading here, and once your operation is complete...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            completion();
        });
    });
}
```

In your view controller's handling method, call it like this:

```
[downloader downloadImagesWithCompletion:^(void) {
{
    // your downloader is now complete, run your UI updates
}];
```

**Note:** this example doesn't include any return values in the completion block, but you can easily [do that as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180552/implementing-a-method-taking-a-block-to-use-as-callback).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to think as UIViewController is a boss. That means UIViewController starts downloading a image, handle the completion, and set Tabbar image. The class of download image process is just a worker. The worker delegates a boss to important decisions.

The class of download image process tries to set Tabbar image directly is not a good idea. It's a good idea to design the class has a delegate protocol or a block function to tell 'someone' to complete the download of image.

You'd better to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library. The library is designed like I said.